# Comment-reply system post succesfully comments without refreshing page, but not replies

Tags: php, jquery

I have created a php, jquery comment-reply system that works perfect. It works like facebook. User posts a comment and then a user can add a reply. Jquery used in order to view comments without refreshing the page each time a user posts a comment. Although I did this and works with comments, it is not working with the relies. In order to view replies I have to refresh the page. Any idea how to fix this?

This is my main page, wall.php :

```
<?php
<script> 
 $(document).ready(function(){                          
  $("#comment_process").click(function(){
    if($("#comment_text").val() != ""){ 
        $.post("comments.php?action=post", { comment: $("#comment_text").val() }, function(data) {
            $(".comments").html(data);
            $("#comment_text").val("");
         });
       } 
     });   
   });   
</script>

<div class="comment_container"> <div class="comment_form">
<textarea id="comment_text"/> </textarea>
</div></div>
<div class="comments">  <?php include_once("comments.php");?>    </div>
?>
```

The next page called comments.php :

```
<?php
 require_once('core/init.php');
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('.reply').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        var comments_id = $(this).attr('comments_id');
        var reply = $(this).val();
        $.post('reply.php', {"data_comments_id":comments_id, "data_reply":reply});  
        $('.reply').val('');    
      }
    });
  });
</script>

function getComments(){
$comments = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY comment_date DESC ") or die (mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0){
  $comments = " <div class='each_comment'> There are no comments ...</div> ";
}
else
{   
   while ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

    $comments .= "Says : <div class='each_comment'> ".$row['comment_date']." ".$row['comment'];
    $comments .= "<input type='text' class='reply' comments_id='{$row['comments_id']}' />";

    echo "<div class='replies'>";
    $reply_query = mysql_query("SELECT reply_id, reply, reply_date FROM comments_reply WHERE comments_id='{$row['comments_id']}' ");

    while ($run_reply= mysql_fetch_assoc($reply_query)) {
      $reply_id = $run_reply['reply_id'];
      $reply = $run_reply['reply'];
      $reply_date = $run_reply['reply_date'];                               
    $comments .= "Replied: $reply_date  $reply   ";

    echo"</div>";

    $comments .= "</div>"; 
  }
 }
return $comments;  
}

function postComments($comment){
 $comment = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($comment));
 if(isset($comment) && empty($comment)){
    $sql = mysql_query(" INSERT INTO `comments` (comment, comment_date) VALUES ('".$comment."', now()) ");
 }
 return getComments();
}

if((isset($_GET['action'])) && ($_GET['action'] == "post")) {
postComments($_POST['comment']);
}

echo getComments();        
?>
```

and finally this is my reply.php page  :

```
<?php  
require_once('core/init.php');

$comments_id = $_POST['data_comments_id'];
$reply = $_POST['data_reply'];

if(isset($reply) && !empty($reply)){ 
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments_reply VALUES ('', '$comments_id', '$reply', now()) "); 
}

?>
```

Comment: You must be getting errors right?

Comment: no I do not get errors...everything works fine. My only problem is that replies do not appears without refreshing the page, as I do with comments. If I refresh the page ofcourse I can see succesfully the replies to each comment. All I want is to get replies without refreshing the pages as I do with comments

Comment: How can you do `<?php <script>..` without any errors? Thats JavaScript inside PHP without escaping it.

Comment: I use </script> if you see at the end , I dont know why it shows it like that now

Comment: This can't work, you put HTML inside PHP without echoing, escaping or closing the PHP part.